# ipython notebook arrange plots horizontally

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Currently, when creating two consecutive plots in an ipython notebook, they are displayed one below the other:

[image]

I'm wondering if there's any way to have them displayed in rows until the space runs out in the window. So for the first two plots, the output would look like this:

[image]

I realize that I can do something similar by arranging subplots in a grid, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it automatically so that plots are wrapped onto the next 'line' when the space runs out?

Answer (score 12):

This works for me in Python 3.5, Jupyter 4.4.0.

The plots "flow around" when you resize the browser window, to fill the horizontal space.

The plots can also be different sizes (try substituting `figsize=(3+i/3,2+i/4)` - see the second image below)

(Just realised how old this question is; I look periodically for the same thing.  I confess the code is cobbled together from other web examples, but I've lost the references now)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import HTML
import io
import base64


class FlowLayout(object):
    ''' A class / object to display plots in a horizontal / flow layout below a cell '''
    def __init__(self):
        # string buffer for the HTML: initially some CSS; images to be appended
        self.sHtml =  """
        <style>
        .floating-box {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid #888888;  
        }
        </style>
        """

    def add_plot(self, oAxes):
        ''' Saves a PNG representation of a Matplotlib Axes object '''
        Bio=io.BytesIO() # bytes buffer for the plot
        fig = oAxes.get_figure()
        fig.canvas.print_png(Bio) # make a png of the plot in the buffer

        # encode the bytes as string using base 64 
        sB64Img = base64.b64encode(Bio.getvalue()).decode()
        self.sHtml+= (
            '<div class="floating-box">'+ 
            '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}\n">'.format(sB64Img)+
            '</div>')

    def PassHtmlToCell(self):
        ''' Final step - display the accumulated HTML '''
        display(HTML(self.sHtml))




oPlot = FlowLayout() # create an empty FlowLayout

# Some fairly regular plotting from Matplotlib
gX = np.linspace(-5,5,100) # just used in the plot example
for i in range(10): # plot 10 charts
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(3,2)) # same size plots
                           # figsize=(3+i/3,2+i/4)) # different size plots
    ax.plot(gX, np.sin(gX*i)) # make your plot here
    oPlot.add_plot(ax) # pass it to the FlowLayout to save as an image
    plt.close() # this gets rid of the plot so it doesn't appear in the cell


oPlot.PassHtmlToCell()
```

[image: Charts in Flow Layout]

[image: Plots of varying size]

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do this:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np
   ...: xs = np.linspace(0,100,100)
   ...: fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
   ...: axs[0].plot(xs, xs * xs)
   ...: axs[1].plot(xs, np.sqrt(xs))
   ...:
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This certainly works, but I was trying to avoid indicating which column I want to put it in. This is in order to potentially rearrange the plots when the window is resized.

Comment: Additionally, this causes the plots to shrink, as they're now subplots of a single larger plot, which has whatever default size.  It would be nicer if they could be arranged in-place, without regard to how many plots you want to put there.

Answer (score 6):

Because the question was posed quite some time ago, I will propose an updated solution for those finding this question via search engines.

Since Jupyter has largely replaced the IPython notebook and Jupyter Lab is planned to replace Jupyter, my solution is implemented in Jupyter Lab 0.35.4.

In this environment, I find it extremely useful to evaluate a cell that reads:

```html
%%html

<style>
    .jp-OutputArea-child {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

This allows for better utilization of vertical space by allowing outputs areas, especially plots, to float side by side.  I wish a more refined variant of this were the default behavior.

Browsers are not currently supporting CSS parent selectors, but according to the [selectors level 4 working draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), it would be better to use something like the following if browsers start supporting it:

```html
%%html

<style>
    .jp-OutputArea-child:has(> .jp-RenderedImage) {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I don't see how it works. Do I run it once in the beginning of the notebook?

Comment: Yes, many of my notebooks have a single standalone cell near the top with the indicated content.  Whenever I evaluate that cell, it causes previously created and future plots to float side by side.

Comment: In Jupyter Lab 2.2.6, this causes images to plot on top of each other.

Comment: This proposed solution has no effect on Colab.  Plots still follow one another vertically just as before, not horizontally.

Comment: The 2nd snippet does not work (anymore?, or only) for me under Jupyter Lab Version 3.0.16. The 1st snippet works indeed! Under Firefox 75.0 (64-bit) here.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris thanks for giving it a try!  As stated in the answer the first snippet should work (as you saw) now, while the second snippet might work better in the future if browsers start supporting CSS Level 4 selectors.  So it's not that the second snipped used to work, but that it should eventually work.  :)

Comment: Is there a way to use this in a limited way, only particular cells? Thanks

Comment: More recently I would recommend using ipywidgets, and this gives the ability to only apply this styling to a particular cells.

Answer (score 1):

Nowaday this works with `ipywidgets`:

```py
# Select ipywidget output for matplotlib
%matplotlib widget

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)

# Capture each plot in an Output object instead of displaying outright
output1 = ipywidgets.Output()
with output1:
    # Restrict the size, otherwise the full horizontal space will be taken
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(4, 3))
    fig.canvas.toolbar_position = 'bottom'
    axes.plot(xs, xs * xs)
    
output2 = ipywidgets.Output()
with output2:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(4, 3))
    fig.canvas.toolbar_position = 'bottom'
    axes.plot(xs, np.sqrt(xs))

output3 = ipywidgets.Output()
with output3:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(4, 3))
    fig.canvas.toolbar_position = 'bottom'
    axes.plot(xs, xs)
```

Now you can use a `HBox` with wrapping layout to show the figures side by side with wrapping:

[image: Using HBox to display figures side by side]

See https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/ for more examples with matplotlib and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174258/450068 on using flex wrap!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there isn't away to do so without the subplot or grid plot methods. As for the plot size, you can specify their sizes with something like `ax[0].axes([.65, .6, .2, .2])` or `plt.subplots(1, 2, figuresize=(12,4))`. Unfortunately, this is how matplotlib is setup. If you use the interpreter, you can resize the GUI.