# Displaying many ipywidgets using flex-box

Tags: flexbox, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am trying to use the option `layout={'flex-flow': 'flex-wrap'}` as described in the documentation [Flex-Flow-Reference](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#flex-flow) on ipywidgets, but do not get it to work in neither jupterlab nor notebook frontend.

In the [multi-checkbox example](https://gist.github.com/pbugnion/5bb7878ff212a0116f0f1fbc9f431a5c), changing line 12, does not work:

```py
options_widget = widgets.VBox(options, layout={'flex-flow': 'flex-wrap'})
multi_select = widgets.VBox([search_widget, options_widget])
```

Do you see a possibility adding `layout={'flex-flow': 'flex-wrap'}`  instead of `{'overflow': 'scroll'}`?
What am I missing in specifying the options?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example, I tend to control the wrap through creating a `Layout` object.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
descriptions = 'abcdefgh'
search_widget = widgets.Text()
options_dict = {description: widgets.Checkbox(description=description, value=False) for description in descriptions}
options = [options_dict[description] for description in descriptions]
options_widget = widgets.VBox(options, layout=widgets.Layout(flex_flow='row wrap'))
multi_select = widgets.VBox([search_widget, options_widget])
```

More examples using the `Layout` object can be found in the docs: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#Examples

Comment: Thanks for the adapted example. I did not get that I have to construct a class with the properties

Comment: Yes I struggled with the flexbox terms, I find myself constructing a `Layout` object more often now.