# How to display two figures, side by side, in a Jupyter cell

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# load data
df = sns.load_dataset('penguins', cache=False)

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='bill_length_mm', y='bill_depth_mm', hue='sex')
plt.show()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='flipper_length_mm', y='body_mass_g', hue='sex')
plt.show()
```

When I draw two plots with seaborn, in one cell, in jupyter, I get this view:

[image]

I want to draw the plots, side by side, like this:

plot1    plot2

How I should do this?

#### Updated:

Not two plots on one figure, but two plots on two separate figures.

- This is not the solution being sought, because it's two plots on one figure.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.plotType(someData, ax=ax[0])  # plot1
sns.plotType(someData, ax=ax[1])  # plot2
fig.show()
```

- The solutions from the proposed duplicate [ipython notebook arrange plots horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754976/ipython-notebook-arrange-plots-horizontally), do not work

  - The option with `%html` causes the figures to plot on top of each other
  - Additionally, other options were for `ipython`, not Jupyter, or recommended creating subplots..

Comment: You should accept the close vote, my markdown option is basically the same as offered in the duplicate and that question and answer are older.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **Markdown** seems to be the easiest option because it does not require loading any additional packages, nor does it require multiple lines of code.
- This question is about displaying two figures, side by side.

  - Separate figures, side by side, executed from a code cell, does not work.
- You will need to create separate figures, and then use `plt.savefig('file.jpg')` to save each figure to a file.
- Tested with `jupyterlab v4.1.4`, `ipython v8.2.0`, `ipywidgets v8.1.2`

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
df = sns.load_dataset('penguins', cache=False)

# create and save figure
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='bill_length_mm', y='bill_depth_mm', hue='sex')
plt.savefig('bill.jpg')
plt.close()  # prevents figure from being displayed when code cell is executed

# create and save new figure
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='flipper_length_mm', y='body_mass_g', hue='sex')
plt.savefig('flipper.jpg')
plt.close()  # prevents figure from being displayed when code cell is executed
```

#### Markdown

- Once the figures are saved to a file, they can be displayed side by side, by loading them in a markdown cell.

  - If the images are to large, the second figure will go to a new line.
- Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451881/7758804) without being a table.

```
**Bill**: ![](bill.jpg)  **Flipper**: ![](flipper.jpg)
```

[image]

- Then execute the cell

[image]

---

### Other Options

- [How do I make 2 images appear side by side in Jupyter notebook (iPython)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50559000/7758804)
- [How to include two pictures side by side in Markdown for IPython Notebook (Jupyter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33647774/7758804)

#### `HTML` and `IPython.display`

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML(f"<table><tr><td><img src='bill.jpg'></td><td><img src='flipper.jpg'></td></tr></table>"))
```

[image]

#### `ipywidgets` and `IPython.display`

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import IPython.display as display

# read the image files
img1 = open('bill.jpg', 'rb').read()
img2 = open('flipper.jpg', 'rb').read()

# create the image widgets
widget1 = widgets.Image(value=img1, format='jpeg')
widget2 = widgets.Image(value=img2, format='jpeg')

# create a box widget for the image widgets
box = widgets.Box([widget1, widget2])

# display box
display(box)
```

[image]

#### `imshow`

- Read the images directly with `matplotlib` and display them with `imshow`, but the plot axis must also be set to off.

```py
# read images
img_A = mpimg.imread('bill.jpg')
img_B = mpimg.imread('flipper.jpg')

# create the subplot axis
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(11, 8))

# plot the images
ax1.imshow(img_A)
ax2.imshow(img_B)

# turn of the axis
ax1.axis('off')
_ = ax2.axis('off')
```

- axis on

[image]

- axis off

[image]